# extension of a function in n-dimension preserving smoothness

Tags: exponential-function, smooth-functions

Consider the following problem. 
I have an arbitrary function $f : \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ with $\Omega$ a compact set, and f is of class $C^k$ over $\Omega$. 
I want to extend the value of $f$ all over $\mathbb{R}^n$ using a function decreasing exponentially fast toward minus infinity in all direction, and preserving the smoothness of $f$ :

$$\lim_{||x||_2 \rightarrow + \infty} g(x) = - \infty$$

$$ g(x) = f(x), \forall x \in \Omega, \quad g \in C^k$$

Do you know what extension of f could satisfy those conditions ?

Comment: The only real problem you have is to actually extend in a $C^k$ way. What happens outside the compact set can be adjusted by adding a suitable function (that decreases as fast as you wish and using a smooth cut-off it does also not change the values in $\Omega$). So, can you extend it in a $C^k$ way?

Comment: I think about something like this : Consider $x^*$ the orthogonal projection of x on $\Omega$, then I would define g as $g (x)=  f (x)- e^{||x-x^*||^2_2} + 1$. What do you think ? Also in my problem, $\Omega$ is a hypercube so I can easily find the orthogonal projection

Comment: Do you mean $g(x)= f(x^*) - e^{\Vert x-x^* \Vert_2^2} +1$? So the only thing you have to prove is that the projection is $C^k$.

Comment: yes that's what I meant, I forgot the $^*$. So how do I prove that the projection is $C^k$ ? do you have any tips ?

Comment: I am not sure it is even true. Maybe you loose one derivative. However, you said, you are looking at a special case?

Comment: Yes I'm specifically looking at $\Omega$ being a hypercube

Comment: But a hypercube is not $C^k$. What do you mean by $f$ being $C^k$ over $\Omega$?

Comment: I mean that we can differentiate $f$ k times over $\Omega$, $\Omega$ being a hyper-square. Do you say it's not possible because a hyper-square is not an open set ? In that case if we consider the "biggest" open set contained in $\Omega$ instead, could that work ?

Comment: There are several things that "$f$ is $C^k$ on $\Omega$" can mean. Being $C^k$ on the interior is not a good idea, then you allow $f$ to blow-up at the boundary (and you will not be able to extend).